Periodic Task Not Execute With Celery Beat
I am currently working on automating periodic tasks using Celery, Celery Beat, and Redis in my Django project. I've set up Celery Beat to schedule tasks and have a periodic task that I want to run at specific intervals. Both Celery Beat and the Celery worker are running without any errors, and the periodic task is successfully created and visible in the Django Celery Beat database.
However, the task does not get executed once the time interval is reached. The task I am referring to is
 'task': 'stripeapp.tasks.create_google_sheet_with_payments_task'
Despite the task being scheduled and visible in the periodic tasks list, it doesn't seem to be triggered or executed by Celery. I have double-checked my task definition and Celery configurations, but the issue persists. I would like to understand why the task is not being executed and how I can fix this issue to ensure that the periodic task runs as expected.
Tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule
import json
from .models import TaskSchedule
from datetime import timedelta
from .stripe_to_sheet_saving import create_google_sheet_with_payments
from django.utils import timezone

@shared_task
def schedule_automated_tasks():
    print("Scheduling automated tasks.")
    
    # Log all existing periodic tasks for debugging
    existing_tasks = PeriodicTask.objects.all()
    for task in existing_tasks:
        print(task.name, task.task, task.interval, task.expires)

    # Get tasks from TaskSchedule model where status is 'running'
    running_tasks = TaskSchedule.objects.filter(status='running')

    for task_schedule in running_tasks:
        print(f"Found task schedule: {task_schedule}")

        task = task_schedule.task
        frequency = task.stripe_source.run_frequency if task.stripe_source else None
        occurrence = task.stripe_source.occurence if task.stripe_source else None
        end_date = task_schedule.end_date

        # Determine the interval based on frequency
        interval = get_interval_from_frequency(frequency)

        if interval is None:
            print(f"Invalid frequency: {frequency} for task {task.id}. Skipping.")
            continue  # Invalid frequency, skip

        # Check if the task should be marked as complete
        running_count = TaskSchedule.objects.filter(task=task, status='running').count()
        if occurrence is not None and end_date is None and running_count >= occurrence:
            task_schedule.status = 'complete'  # Update status to complete
            task_schedule.save()
            print(f"Task {task.id} marked as complete due to occurrence limit.")

        # Schedule the task using Celery Beat
        periodic_task, created = PeriodicTask.objects.get_or_create(
            name=f"Task-{task.id}",
            defaults={
                'task': 'stripeapp.tasks.create_google_sheet_with_payments_task',
                'interval': IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=interval, period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS)[0],
                'args': json.dumps([
                    task.data_mapper_user.email, 
                    task.google_sheet_destination.sheet_name if task.google_sheet_destination else None,
                    task.stripe_source.payment_options, 
                    task.stripe_source.previous_data_option, 
                    task.id
                ]),
                'expires': end_date,  # Set expiration 
            }
        )
        
        if created:
            print(f"Created new periodic task: {periodic_task.name}")
        else:
            print(f"Updated existing periodic task: {periodic_task.name}")
            # Update task arguments
            periodic_task.args = json.dumps([
                task.data_mapper_user.email, 
                task.google_sheet_destination.sheet_name if task.google_sheet_destination else None,
                task.stripe_source.payment_options, 
                task.stripe_source.previous_data_option,  
                task.id
            ])
            periodic_task.save()

        # Update next_run and previous_run
        task.next_run = timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=interval)  # Ensure this is timezone-aware
        task.previous_run = timezone.now()  # Ensure this is timezone-aware
        task.save()
        print(f"Updated next_run for task {task.id} to {task.next_run}.")

        # Log how much time remains until the next run
        remaining_time = task.next_run - timezone.now()
        print(f"Time remaining until the next execution of task {task.id}: {remaining_time.total_seconds()} seconds.")


def get_interval_from_frequency(frequency):
    """Returns the interval in seconds based on the frequency string."""
    frequency_map = {
        'daily': 60,           # seconds in a day
        'hourly': 3600,          # seconds in an hour
        'weekly': 604800,        # seconds in a week
        'monthly': 2592000,      # seconds in a month
        'quarterly': 7776000,    # seconds in a quarter
        'semi_annually': 15552000,  # seconds in six months
        'annually': 31536000     # seconds in a year
    }
    return frequency_map.get(frequency)


@shared_task
def create_google_sheet_with_payments_task(email, google_sheet_name, payment_option, frequency_filter, custom_start_date=None, custom_end_date=None, task_id=None):
    print(f"Running task for email: {email}, sheet name: {google_sheet_name}.")
    return create_google_sheet_with_payments(
        email=email,
        google_sheet_name=google_sheet_name,
        payment_option=payment_option,
        frequency_filter=frequency_filter,
        custom_start_date=custom_start_date,
        custom_end_date=custom_end_date,
        task_id=task_id
    )

settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'  
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'schedule_automated_tasks': {
        'task': 'stripeapp.tasks.schedule_automated_tasks',
        'schedule': 60.0,  # run every minute
    },
}

celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'datamapper.settings')

app = Celery('datamapper')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

output
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,128: INFO/MainProcess] Task stripeapp.tasks.schedule_automated_tasks[199e547d-a0f2-46da-a89f-16312893bac0] received
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,130: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Scheduling automated tasks.
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,158: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task-1
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,158: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4]
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,158: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] stripeapp.tasks.create_google_sheet_with_payments_task
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,159: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4]
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,159: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] every 60 seconds
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,159: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4]
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,159: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 2024-12-31 00:00:00+00:00
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,166: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Found task schedule: TaskSchedule - Task ID: 1, Status: running, Run Time: 2024-10-19 10:02:52.361584+00:00
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,179: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Updated existing periodic task: Task-1
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,241: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Updated next_run for task 1 to 2024-10-19 16:22:22.237695+00:00.
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,241: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Time remaining until the next execution of task 1: 59.996074 seconds.
[2024-10-19 16:21:22,241: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task stripeapp.tasks.schedule_automated_tasks[199e547d-a0f2-46da-a89f-16312893bac0] succeeded in 0.11220735599999898s: None
